# Determinant is the same for $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us have $A=(a_{ij})$ arbitrary matrix and for $B=(b_{ij})$ matrix we have $b_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}$.

Prove, that $det A = det B$.

I tried with some examples, and the determinant is same, but how should I prove it in general? I tried to use the general formula(Leibniz formula), but it didn't really seem to help me out. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best approach is to prove it by induction on the size of the matrix.

Comment: That seems to be an interesting method, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let the size of the matrices be $n$. Then
$$ \det A = \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sign}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i, \sigma(i)}. $$
Also,
$$ \det B = \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sign}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n b_{i, \sigma(i)}
= \sum_\sigma \operatorname{sign}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+\sigma(i)} a_{i, \sigma(i)}.$$
The point is to now notice that $$\prod_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+\sigma(i)} = (-1)^{1+2+\dots+n+1+2+\dots+n} = (-1)^{2k} = 1$$ where $k=1+\dots+n$. Hence each term in the sum matches up exactly.

Comment: Wow, very elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Note that $(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}=(-1)^ia_{ij}(-1)^j$. Therefore $B=DAD$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,-1,1,\ldots)$.